# How to put nib file in collection view in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am one problem in use collection view. 
How to put nib file in collection view?
I will create image slider in collection view.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBDesignable class Menu: UIView {

    var view: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        xibSetup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        xibSetup()
    }

    func xibSetup() {

        view = loadViewFromNib()
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {

        let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "Menu", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

        return view
    }

    etc etc ...
}
```

[image: Nib Name]

[image: Nib Identity Inspector]

Then add a UIView to your Main.storyboard as with a Menu class in the Identity Inspector for that view.

Comment: Why are you adding the view obtained in the nib as a subview instead of just returning the view? If the view contained in the NIB happens to be a `Menu` view, it will fall in an endless loop.